# How is StaticPropertyChanged recognized?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, static

Is the StaticPropertyChanged event simply a convention (regarding names) or what mechanism does WPF use to recognize this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventhandler raising static property change notification must have one of two possible signatures.

Note that it must be static itself, so it cannot just be a regular propertychanged eventhandler

This is explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/getting-started/whats-new?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#static_properties

> **Binding to static properties**
>
> You can use static properties as the source of a data binding. The data binding engine recognizes when the
> property's value changes if a static event is raised. For example, if
> the class SomeClass defines a static property called MyProperty,
> SomeClass can define a static event that is raised when the value of
> MyProperty changes. The static event can use either of the following
> signatures.
>
> public static event EventHandler MyPropertyChanged;
>
> public static event EventHandler
> StaticPropertyChanged;
>
> Note that in the first case, the class exposes a static event named
> PropertyNameChanged that passes EventArgs to the event handler. In the
> second case, the class exposes a static event named
> StaticPropertyChanged that passes PropertyChangedEventArgs to the
> event handler. A class that implements the static property can choose
> to raise property-change notifications using either method.